# Function in Oracle that returns 2 different columns of a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, stored-functions

I'm trying to create a function that returns 2 different columns in a single table, can anyone help me with that?

I've already tried this way:

```
CREATE FUNCTION return_id_grade(subjectId IN NUMBER, semesterYear IN DATE , n IN INT, option IN INT)
RETURN NUMBER
                IS studentId NUMBER(5),
                IS studentGrade NUMBER(2,1);
   BEGIN
                SELECT DISTINCT student_id INTO studentId,
                       grade INTO studentGrade
                    FROM (SELECT studentId, grade, dense_rank() over (ORDER BY grade desc) rank FROM old_students) 
                        WHERE subject_id = subjectId 
                            AND semester_year = semesterYear
                            AND rank = n
                            AND rownum <= 1
    CASE 
                WHEN option = 1 then RETURN(student_id)
                WHEN option = 2 then RETURN(grade)
    END;

END;
```

I expected to output the n'NTH grade of an university class and the student Id, but the actual can just output the option received on parameter field.

Comment: Just from a quick reading: You are missing ; after the SELECT INTO statement. Then, the CASE expression with RETURN statements should be the other way around: `RETURN CASE WHEN option = 1 then student_id WHEN option = 2 then grade END;`

Comment: You're right, I was missing it...Thank you...

Comment: Also, you have two `is` keywords. And that's one heck of an indent size. Normally people use 2 or 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

a.You cant use Select colum1 INTO variable1 , colum2  INTO variable2 . It has to be like :
Select column1 , column2 INTO variable1 , variable 2

b.Create an object type and use it as out parameter in a procedure

c.Have the option condition after the procedure is called.

Sample Code:

```
      CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ty_obj_idgrade AS OBJECT
      (studentId    NUMBER(5)
      ,studentGrade    NUMBER(2,1)
       );



      CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE return_id_grade(
                                        subjectId IN NUMBER, 
                                        semesterYear IN DATE , 
                                        n IN INT, 
                                       -- options IN INT
                                        ,p_idgrade OUT ty_obj_idgrade) IS
       BEGIN
            SELECT DISTINCT student_id --INTO studentId,
                            ,grade --INTO studentGrade
                       INTO p_idgrade.studentId
                            ,p_idgrade.grade
                       FROM (SELECT studentId
                                    ,grade
                                    ,dense_rank() over (ORDER BY grade desc) rank 
                                    ,subject_id
                                    ,semester_year
                               FROM old_students )
                WHERE  subject_id = subjectId
                  AND  semester_year = semesterYear
                  AND  rank = n
                  AND  rownum <= 1;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('we are inside when others -->'||sqlerrm);

END;
```

Call your procedure.

Since options was used as IN parameter , it should be availabe outside the prc/fnc
    So this can be done after the prc/fnc call
    If options = 1
    THEN
       value := p_idgrade.conatct
    ELSE
       value := p_idgrade.grade
    END IF;

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfectly understood!!thanks for the answer.. I was wondering some other way I don't use the option variable, and if there's another way to output the following result in example: StudentId and StudentGrade.                                     ,      002.                   9,5.

Answer (score 0):

Did not try compiling it, but something like this should be close.

```
CREATE FUNCTION return_id_grade(subjectId IN NUMBER, semesterYear IN DATE , n IN INT, option IN INT)
RETURN NUMBER IS
studentId NUMBER(5),
studentGrade NUMBER(2,1);
   BEGIN
                SELECT DISTINCT student_id, grade
                INTO studentId, studentGrade
                    FROM (SELECT studentId, grade, dense_rank() over (ORDER BY grade desc) rank FROM old_students) 
                        WHERE subject_id = subjectId 
                            AND semester_year = semesterYear
                            AND rank = n
                            AND rownum <= 1;
    IF option = 1 then 
         RETURN studentId ;
    ELSE
        RETURN studentGrade ;
    END IF;
    END;

END;
```

However, this function is really not a good design.  A function should perform a single task. If you want to return both items, create a PL/SQL record type, and use a stored procedure with an OUT parameter and return that in the procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser!! But is there a way I can output the result in example: StudentId and StudentGrade.                                     ,      002.                   9,5.     Instead of using the variable option?

Comment: Not sure I understand "not using a variable"?  How do you expect to reference the results if you don't store them somewhere?

Comment: Actually I was thinking about having both results at the same time (StudentId and His grade), instead of having to choose one of them with the variable option.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly try to use `OPTION` in query as following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION RETURN_ID_GRADE (
    SUBJECTID      IN             NUMBER,
    SEMESTERYEAR   IN             DATE,
    N              IN             INT,
    OPTION         IN             INT
) RETURN NUMBER IS
    LV_RETURN_NUMBER   NUMBER(6, 1);
BEGIN
    -- QUERY TO FETCH REQUIRED DATA ONLY
    SELECT -- DISTINCT -- DISTINCT IS NOT NEEDED AS ROWNUM <= 1 IS USED
        CASE
            WHEN OPTION = 1 THEN STUDENT_ID
            ELSE GRADE
        END AS LV_RETURN_NUMBER
    INTO LV_RETURN_NUMBER -- STORE VALUE BASED ON OPTION
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                STUDENTID,
                GRADE,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER(
                    ORDER BY
                        GRADE DESC
                ) RANK
            FROM
                OLD_STUDENTS
        )
    WHERE
        SUBJECT_ID = SUBJECTID
        AND SEMESTER_YEAR = SEMESTERYEAR
        AND RANK = N
        AND ROWNUM <= 1;

    RETURN LV_RETURN_NUMBER; -- RETURN THE VARIABLE

END;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Perfectly worked!! But is there any other option instead of using the variable option, that I can output the result in example: StudentId and StudentGrade.                                     ,      002.                   9,5.      Tnks for the anwser!